# FileStream c# and try and catch

Tags: c#

```
public  static StringBuilder odczyt(string nazwa)
    {
        FileStream plik;
        StringBuilder dane = new StringBuilder("");
        try
        {
            plik = new FileStream(nazwa,FileMode.Open);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Brak pliku {0}", nazwa);
        }
        int w;
        do
        {
            w = plik.ReadByte();
            if(w != -1)
                dane.Append((char)w);
        }
        while( (w > 0) );
        plik.Close();
        return dane;
    }
}
```

Its my simple function, and it was working, but now i dont know how it has happend it dont.
Monodevelop say plik does not have assigned value? 
Coudl someone explain why ?

Comment: Maybe add `catch(Exception)` below your current 'catch'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning your `plik` inside the `try catch` block, which means that if you throw an exception during the assignment then you'll be trying to use it without having first assigned it. Move your code after the `try catch` block into the block thus:

```
    public static StringBuilder odczyt(string nazwa)
    {
        FileStream plik;
        StringBuilder dane = new StringBuilder("");
        try
        {
            plik = new FileStream(nazwa, FileMode.Open);

            int w;
            do
            {
                w = plik.ReadByte();
                if (w != -1)
                    dane.Append((char)w);
            }
            while ((w > 0));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Brak pliku {0}", nazwa);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (plik != null)
            {
                plik.Close();
            }
        }

        return dane;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:
1. check the file exist using FileExist(filename) first;
2. use: using (plik = new FileStream(nazwa, FileMode.Open)) for read file

```
if (File.Exist(nazwa))
{
  using (FileStream  plik = new FileStream(nazwa, FileMode.Open))
  {
      ..... do other stuff
  }
}
else
{
 // file not exist
}
```

check the syntax as I type it directly.

the exception popped because it may close the plik without init it because of the try catch.